# well-defined sections of twisted sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let us consider the twisting sheaf of Serre, $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$ where $X=\operatorname{Proj} k[x_0, \dots,x_n]$. We define

$$ \mathcal{O}_X (1) = k[x_0, \dots, x_n](1)^{\sim} $$

Then for some homogeneous $f$ of degree $m$

$$\mathcal{O}_X(1)_{D(f)}= k[x_0,\dots, x_n](1)_f = \{\frac{x}{f^k} \vert x \in k[x_0, \dots, x_n]_{km+1} \}$$

Thus the difference in degree in the fractions is $1$.

My problem with this is the following:

For the original description of the structure sheaf of $\operatorname{Proj}$ it was it was important that our fractions were of degree zero. I thought we do this because when we consider projective space, for example, we want these sections to be well defined. 
However, with the description as above, our local sections would cease being well-defined.

Is this now ok or what am I not understanding?

Comment: These things are not functions; they are sections of the sheaf $O_X(1)$.

Comment: Now, it is all ok! ;)

Answer (score 0):

For example on $\mathcal{O}(1)$ the global sections $x_0, \dots, x_1$ are indeed well-defined section of $\mathcal{O}(1)$. We can think of them as "coordinates".